# For the recertification flight(s) of the 737Max, will the FAA want to see a live runaway stabilizer?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-controls, boeing-737, aircraft-certification

With Boeing ready to start the testing Monday, will the FAA want to see a simulated runaway trim failure in flight?

Comment: If the failure effect constitutes hazardous criticality, it *usually* won't be done in flight.

Comment: As far as I've seen, the FAA has not published the exact plan the test flights. The only quote I could find is "Testing is expected to take several days, and will include a wide array of flight maneuvers and emergency procedures to enable the agency to assess whether the changes meet FAA certification standards." ([CNN](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/06/28/business/boeing-737-max-test-flights-approved/index.html)).